# What's the bottleneck of a TCP2HTTP(urllib) Proxy ThreadingTcpServer in Python

Tags: python, urllib

I have implmented a TCP to HTTP proxy server using urllib,

which converts a TCP request to a HTTP request to a specific server,

It's something like this:

```
class RequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        size, = struct.unpack('L', s.recv(4))
        data = s.recv(size)
        assert len(data) == size
        res = urllib.urlopen('http://myserver.com/', encode_data(data)).read()
        s.sendall(res)
        s.shutdown(SHUT_WR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    address = ('', 8080)
    server = socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(address, RequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

But it became very slow on many connections(not too many: about 20) at the same time.

Where is the bottleneck? Is it related with GIL issue?

BTW: I'm on Windows so ForkingMixin is not available here

Comment: @user522809: Isn't HTTP protocol over TCP protocol. Or to say, HTTP would be an application level protocol.

Comment: @pyfunc: Not a general TCP2HTTP proxy. It only converts some specific TCP request to corresponding HTTP request. You can say HTTP is used here as an app level protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use profiler, one of: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script/1922945#1922945